# Run java -jar from bash file

Tags: command-line, bash, java

This is my .sh file and I'm trying to run it from a terminal, but it doesn't work even after checking paths, installing libc6-i386 and simplify it to a direct java call. Until here java path was not recognized. Does someone know how to do it?

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
CLASSPATH=/home/daniel/test/commons-lang3-3.5.jar;/home/daniel/test/test-1.0.0.jar:.
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -classpath $CLASSPATH com.test.Main
exit 0
```

[image: Terminal]

Comment: Seems you have a `;` in your classpath.

Comment: You should add simple quote arround your value.
`CLASSPATH='/home/daniel/test/commons-lang3-3.5.jar;/home/daniel/test/test-1.0.0.jar:.'`

Comment: Does `test.sh` have DOS/Windows line endings? Check with `file test.sh`

Comment: @bac0n seems the right separator is colon https://stackoverflow.com/a/219801/1163543

Comment: @ob2 simple quote seems not allowed in this case

Comment: @steeldriver you are right! the file had CRLF line terminators... I recreated the script without CRTL and replaced the semicolon by colon... the issue was solved! :)